# Конструкция вида if (int & int)

Tags: c#

Встречаю в коде конструкции вида

```
int index = 2;
if ((index & 1) == 1)
{..}
```

Никак не могу понять "сакральный смысл" использования такой конструкции, или это просто в силу привычки люди так пишут.

Comment: Проверка на наличие бита?

Comment: @olegkalenchuk Скорее на четность/нечетность

Comment: то же, что и `index % 2`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Это проверка на чётность/нечётность (конкретно в вашем примере на нечетность).

Суть в двоичном представлении числа, в котором самый младший бит является `2` в степени `0`, то есть это либо `1`, либо `0`. Вот если этот младший бит равен `1`, значит число — нечётное, а если он равен `0` — то число чётное.

Примеры:

`34810` в двоичной – `1010111002`, последний бит `0`, число чётное.

`34710` в двоичной – `1010110112`, последний бит `1`, число нечётное.

`210` в двоичной `102`, чётное.

`510` в двоичной `1012`, нечётное.

P.S. обратил внимание, что в заголовке вопроса указано `int & int`, а не `int & 1`, если же имеется ввиду именно `int & int`, то у побитового `and` более широкое применение.

Comment: Да именно int & int, встречается и такое int & 3 и тд, в этом какой смысл?

Comment: Это используется как проверка на флаг - 1, 2, 4, 8 - битовая маска взаимоисключающих или комбинированных битовых флагов.

Answer (score -1):

`&` - Логическая операция "*И*". Побитное умножение одного числа на другое. По сути приведенная выше конструкция означает умножение.

Comment: Не совсем правильный ответ. Если следовать ему, то true & false будет равняться нулю, а не 1. Смотрите пример в https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx или https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: Daniel! Вы это о чем...?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(true & false);
            Console.WriteLine(true & true);
            Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToInt32(true & false));
            Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToInt32(true & true));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
} Я так и не понял ваш комментарий...!!! Еще раз...О чем Вы...?